# Drupal drush error

Tags: drupal-7, drush

I have installed Composer on C drive (C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data). I have a drupal7 project on D drive (D:\wamp\www\drupal71).

I have installed Drush by this command: **composer global require drush/drush:7.*** and it successfully downloaded but skipped installing because of naming conflicts. Please see the attached screen shot.

Now when I run the drush command drush status, it shows that "*drush is not recognized as an internal or external command*".

Can you please guide / help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the PATH to your environment variables. To do this:

1. Right-click My computer, and go to "Properties"
   [image: Properties]
2. Go to Advanced System Settings
3. In the Avanced tab, click Environment Variables
4. At user variables for User, you should add a line to the "Path" variable ( if you don't have that already create it)
5. You should add the absolute path where your drush file is DON'T FORGET TO PUT ";" before the other paths which may be already there.
6. My drush file absolute path was E:/windrush/vendor/drush/drush so I added like the following picture[image]

Comment: Done as said by you. In my case, the absolute drush path is C:\Documents and Settings\Extralap2\Application Data\Composer\vendor\drush\drush. But as per my original question post, in cmd I typed as d:\wamp\www\drupal71> drush cc, it shows - the same error i.e. "drush is not recognized as an internal or external command".

Comment: check again these steps, it's not a drush problem, it's your environment variable that it's not being recognized

Comment: Its working. I closed the cmd and start again. Thanks buddy!